# Routing back with in a time frame

Tags: vue.js

I am new to coding.In my  app after the submission of a form i will get a message that i have submitted successfully or is it an error.After getting the message i want to revert back the user to my previous page with in 5 seconds.while using $router.push getting 'can not read property of undefine push'If some one knows please...

this the scrip to call

```
enter code here
```

```
 methods: {
      submitForm() {

      formService.hospital({

          firstName: this.firstName,
          ,
          date: new Date(this.date),

          time: this.time
        }) .then(response => {
          response.data;
          console.log(response);
          this.isSuccessMessage = true;
          this.isErrorMessage = false;
          this.$store.dispatch('addPickupAssistanceMessage');
 setTimeout(function(){ this.$router.push('/dashboard'); 5000 });
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log("Error reported from endpoints :", JSON.stringify(error.response));
          this.isErrorMessage = true;
          this.$store.dispatch('addErrorMessage')
          return (this.errorMessage = JSON.stringify(
            error.response.data.errorMessage
          ))
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside the handler function passed to [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), which uses [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp).$router, which is a property of the instance. The problem can be solved with [arrow functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp).

```
setTimeout(() => { this.$router.push('/dashboard'); }, 5000);
```

Comment: thanks federico-dondi ,it worked when i used your code.

Comment: Happy to be helpful.

Comment: Hi how can i add a simple countdown to show the user at the time of revert using the same setTimeout(() => { this.$router.push('/dashboard'); }, 5000);